# How to assign new column as string to Pandas Assign

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

How can i assign string as newcolumn to pandas.assign

Example:

```
newcolumn = 'myColumn'
    if(newcolumn != ''):
      sourcePandas = sourcePandas.assign(newcolumn = sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(func))
```

Above doesn't throw any error, but creates new column with name `newcolumn` instead `myColumn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Assuming `sourcePandas` is your dataframe,

- Replace `newcolumn =` by `f'{newcolumn}':` inside `sourcePandas.assign()`.

```
newcolumn = 'myColumn'
    if(newcolumn != ''):
      sourcePandas = sourcePandas.assign(**{f'{newcolumn}': sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(func)})
```

---

### Assigning Multiple Columns Simultaneously

You can assign multiple columns simultaneously as well, using `df.assign()`. The `**` is used to unpack the dictionary and convert the constituents into a list of key-value pairs for the keyword-arguments: [`pandas.DataFrame.assign(self, **kwargs)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

```py
# df --> dataframe
df.assign(**{'A': np.arange(7), 'B': np.arange(7) + 2})
```

---

### References

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `dict` and then unpack dictionary using `**` to pass as key-word arguments into [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

Ex.:

```py
newcolumn = 'myColumn'
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.assign(**{newcolumn:[0,1,2]})
   myColumn
0         0
1         1
2         2
```

So it would be

```py
newcolumn = 'myColumn'
    if(newcolumn != ''):
      sourcePandas = sourcePandas.assign(**{newcolumn: sourcePandas[row['PrimaryColumn']].apply(func)})
```